# SharePoint 2016 document library drag and drop event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, drag-and-drop

We are using SharePoint 2016 and have sites and document libraries. Is it possible to do some logic when someone drag and drop a document to a document library? For example to set some dynamic text value in a column "TestColumn".

I hope this is possible without doing some server side developing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fire the **ItemAdded** event that is triggered automatically when a file uploaded or dragged and dropped to the document library:

On **ItemAdded**, try to set your `test column` as the following:

```
properties.listItem["TestColumn"] = "your value!";
properties.ListItem.Update();
```

Comment: Is this the server side event receiver where you talking about?

Comment: Yes, I think It's the current logical solution that will match your requirements!

Comment: I dont want to use a server side solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create SharePoint 2010 workflow for library(2013 workflow won't trigger per my testing), when file got uploaded, update the column value.

Comment: I would like to implement some solution for multiple libraries in multiple sitecolelections. I dont think it is a good idea to build for each library or sitecollection the same workflow manually in SP designer.